Override compiler/linker option for selected files in GN build
I want to set the -E compiler option for an arbitrarily selected File123.cpp in my build in order to check the preprocessed source. But since I am using GN, whatever compiler/linker flags I set are applied to all source files.
How do I override build tool options for only a selection of source files. Also, does source_set support C++ files yet?
I tried what was suggested here but I want to avoid having to replicate the entire build steps for the dummy target.

just out of curiosity, can you not not use gn, but invoke the compiler directly? I mean you dont need a whole build system to preprocess a single file, or do you?

Can you look up the rule for file123.cpp in the (generated) Ninja file and just add -E yourself? All GN does is calculate all parameters and stuff them in a ninja rules file.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai from what I understand this build is executed in some kind of virtual environment. Also the target in question is being built somewhere deep inside the whole build. Due to these reasons I haven't yet been able to recreate the environment and dependencies to execute the compile in isolation.

@Botje I'll try your suggestion. I'm new to Ninja though and for reasons mentioned in my reply to 463035818_is_not_an_ai, it is going to be tricky.

You could just modify the ninja file and add the -E for that one file yourself, then run ninja .../File123.o or whatever.
